# Fused location API runtime permissions error

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, location-services, android-fusedlocation, runtime-permissions

I am trying to get the permission for accessing the location and using the **Fusedlocation** provider API for android, however, my app crashes on opening. I reviewed the Google developer documentation and made the changes appropriately to the respective method.

When I get a location, I am passing the coordinates and store them using **SharedPreferences**. Can you please let me know what did I not handle in the program or handle incorrectly?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private final String TAG = "LocationActivity";

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

String lat, lon;
Location mLastLocation;
GridView androidGridView;
String[] gridViewString = {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //checkAppPermission();
    Log.d(TAG, "Test location ..............");
    //setup GoogleApiclient
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    Log.d(TAG, "After build api client");
}
public void checkAppPermission(){
    if (checkPermission()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        requestPermission();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please request permission.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
private boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    Log.d(TAG, "Test location 2..............");
    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

}
private void requestPermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    Log.d(TAG, "requestPermissions..............");
}
//This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    //Checking the request code of our request
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult..............");

    if (requestCode == 1) {

        //If permission is granted
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //Displaying a toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                    showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                        requestPermissions(new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,},
                                                1);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    Log.d(TAG, "GoogleAPIclient init ..............");

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Connect the client.
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    checkAppPermission();
    Log.d(TAG, "inside onconnected");
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000); // Update location every 10 seconds
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        lon = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"" +lat);
    Log.d(TAG,""+ lon);
    Log.d(TAG, "calling storeprefs inside onconnected");
    storeprefs(lat,lon);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // New location has now been determined
    String lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
    String lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Log.i(TAG, lat);
    Log.i(TAG, lon);
    storeprefs(lat,lon);
    // You can now create a LatLng Object for use with maps
    //LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

}
```

Error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.android.wesport, PID: 11572
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.wesport/com.example.android.wesport.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzof.zzd(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.example.android.wesport.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Stack trace 2

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.android.wesport, PID: 5763
              java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
                  at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzi$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzk.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzl.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznt$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoc.zzf(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoc.zzd(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoh.zzd(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzof.zzd(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
                  at com.example.android.wesport.MainActivity.onConnected(MainActivity.java:171)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzl.zzm(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzof.zzk(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzod.zzsb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzod.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoh.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznw.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$1.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzj.zztp(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zze.zztr(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: I have added the stack trace to the reported issue now

Comment: I can see from the error that Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission should be provided to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations, however n the onConnected() method I am calling check permissions(), which verifies the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

You cannot call `requestLocationUpdates()` until `onConnected()` is called. However, you are calling `requestLocationUpdates()` already in `onCreate()`, if you have determined that you hold the runtime permission.

Comment: You are correct.I fixed it, however I still get an error. I have posted my new stack trace above and updated programs just so that only location context is maintained

Comment: @MaheshN: You cannot call `requestLocationUpdates()` until **both** `onConnected()` is called **and** you have the permission. Right now, you are calling `buildGoogleApiClient()` before you have the permission, and then you are calling `requestLocationUpdates()` from `onConnected()` (again, before you have the permission). [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Location/FusedPeriodic) demonstrates how to do this.

Comment: your github link helped. I was able to include the runtime permissions correctly. Thanks for your help